# SQL Group by Sum in Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query I have at present:

```
SELECT dbo.INQUIRY.*, dbo.LINKS.*, dbo.TIMELOG.LOGMINS
FROM dbo.INQUIRY
  INNER JOIN dbo.LINKS ON dbo.INQUIRY.INQUIRY_ID = dbo.LINKS.INQUIRY_ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.TIMELOG ON dbo.INQUIRY.INQUIRY_ID = dbo.TIMELOG.INQUIRY_ID
```

The relationship is One Inquiry to Many Links to Many TimeLog. At the moment it would return 6 rows with INQUIRY_ID of say 71293, with a LOGMINS of row 1, 5 row 2, 12, row 3 8 etc.

What I want to do is sum all the LOGMINS for that one INQUIRYID and have that returned as the result for the row so I don't get 6 rows, just one with the total. Any direction appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT INQUIRY_ID, SUM(Logmins) FROM (...) GROUP BY INQUIRY_ID` you need to have all fields selected in the group by or in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have all fields selected in the `group by` or in an aggregate function.

This is the basic idea.

```
SELECT i.INQUIRY_ID (, other fields not aggregated)
    ,SUM(t.Logmins) [TotalLogMins]
FROM INQUIRY i
INNER JOIN LINKS l 
    ON i.INQUIRY_ID = l.INQUIRY_ID
INNER JOIN TIMELOG t 
    ON i.INQUIRY_ID = t.INQUIRY_ID
GROUP BY i.INQUIRY_ID (, other fields not aggregated)
```